getting FlashBagInterface on session in Symfony 6
I'am upgrading a Symfony app from 5.4 to 6.0
On Symfony 6 it is no longer recomanded to use autowiring on Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface but instead to use session->getFlashBag()->add() as mentionned in the doc here
However the SessionInterface does not contain a method called ->getFlashBag() and all topic I have found (like this one : Error: References interface "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface" but no such service exists - while adding a flash ) reference to it.
How could I get an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface without breaking my linter ?
Thank you
I have tried to autowire Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface  in the constructor but it is no longer supported in Symfony 6.
I have tried to use to use session->getFlashBag()->add() but it raise error from the linter.

Maybe https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/39222 helps?

I think you need to check this manually as described in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/46491

So it looks like I have found the solution.
Thanks to Nico Haase
According to Symfony's Github issues #39222 and #46491 to get the FlashBagInterface you should verify that the session is an istance of FlashBagAwareSessionInterface before calling the ->getFlashBag() method.
It should looks like this :
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\FlashBagInterface;

if ($session instanceof FlashBagAwareSessionInterface) {
   $session->addFlashBag(...);
}

However this method is only available in Symfony 6.2+. For prior version use this :
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\FlashBagInterface;

if ($session instanceof Session) {
   $session->addFlashBag(...);
}


Getting around IDE warnings this way inside a custom session wrapper class in Symfony 6.4, in case this helps someone...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class MyCustomSessionService
{

    public function __construct(
        private RequestStack $requestStack
    ) {}

    private function getSession(): SessionInterface
    {
        return $this->requestStack->getSession();
    }

    public function setFlash(string $name, mixed $value): void
    {
        $session = $this->getSession();
        if ($session instanceof Session) {
            $session->getFlashBag()->add($name, $value);
        }
    }

